# HTML table border not working on IE10

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have the table border working fine in chrome and firefox but when run at the IE 10 totally incorrect. Anyone please help me. Thanks

```
    <StdUI:GridView ID="gvSI" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HideHeader="true"
                        HideFooter="true" Visible="False" OnRowDataBound="gvSI_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="style1" border="1" style="border-width: .05px; border-color: #C0C0C0;">
                   <tr>
                     <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                         End of Certificate Year
                      </td>
                      <td class="style2" colspan="5">
                         <btd>
                              Guaranteed
                       </td>
                      <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                              Total Benefits&nbsp;
                       </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                              Yearly Contribution
                        </td>
                        <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                                    Wakalah Fee
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                                   PRF
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                  Death Benefit (Nonaccidental cause)
                        </td>
                        <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
                                  Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" rowspan="2">
                                      Surrender Value
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="style5">
                          Death Benefit (Non- accidental cause)
                      </td>
                      <td class="style2">
                            Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                      </td>
                      <td class="style2">
                                Surrender Value
                      </td>
                   </tr>
             </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
 <table class="style1" border="0" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #C0C0C0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td style="text-align: center" width="30" >
 <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col1") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="70">
 <asp:label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col2","{0:n2}") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="35">
 <asp:label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col3","{0:n2}") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="50">
 <asp:label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col4","{0:n2}") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="40">
 <asp:label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col5","{0:n2}") %>'>
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="50">
 <asp:label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col6","{0:n2}") %>'>   
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="55">
 <asp:label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col7","{0:n2}") %>'>  
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="52">
 <asp:label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col8","{0:n2}") %>'>  
      </asp:label> </td>
<td style="text-align: center" width="76">
 <asp:label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col9","{0:n2}") %>'>  
      </asp:label> </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
                    </StdUI:GridView>
```

Style for the CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .noborder
    {
        border: none;
    }
    .style1
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .style2
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .style4
    {
        width: 268435424px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .style5
    {
        text-align: center;
        width: 219px;
    }

</style>
```

Image of the gridview table (Chrome)
http://postimg.org/image/rny32vgcx/

Image of the gridview table (IE)
http://postimg.org/image/zfe4esmnb/

Comment: You have used inline style.and also you are using class (class="style1") .
have you added some border styles in class?? 
But those are overridden  by the inline style.

Comment: @Jawad Zeb What should I need to do ?

Comment: post the class="style1" code.

Comment: with the images sent by you, try setting cellpadding and cellspacing property of table to 0. May this will help.

Comment: check the answer i posted @NgMunKeat

Comment: did you add the meta-tags for IE10 ? like this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />`

Comment: You should describe *what the problem is* in the question itself, instead of just showing screen shots and expecting others to compare them. Note that the code posted is not HTML at all but ASP.  You should also reduce the problem to a simple case and present it as just HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your problem is in applying border color .IE does not applies border color because 
""The "border-color" property does not work if it is used alone. Use the "border-style" property to set the borders first.""

so the answer code is:

  <style type="text/css">
        .noborder {
            border: none;
        }

        .style1 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-right-color: #C0C0C0;
            border-bottom-color: #C0C0C0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .style2 {
            text-align: center;
        }



        .style4 {
            width: 268435424px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .style5 {
            text-align: center;
            width: 219px;
        }
        td {
            border-style: solid;
            border-right-color: #C0C0C0;
            border-bottom-color: #C0C0C0;


        }

    </style>



        <table class="style1" border="1" style="border-width: .05px;">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center">End of Certificate Year
                </td>
                <td class="style2" colspan="5">Guaranteed
                </td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Total Benefits&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="style2" rowspan="2">Yearly Contribution
                </td>
                <td class="style2" rowspan="2">Wakalah Fee
                </td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">PRF
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">Death Benefit (Nonaccidental cause)
                </td>
                <td class="style2" rowspan="2">Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                </td>
                <td class="style4" rowspan="2">Surrender Value
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5">Death Benefit (Non- accidental cause)
                </td>
                <td class="style2">Death Benefit (Accidental cause)
                </td>
                <td class="style2">Surrender Value
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="style1" border="0" style="border-width: 1px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="30">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col1") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="70">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col2","{0:n2}") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="35">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col3","{0:n2}") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="50">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col4","{0:n2}") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="40">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col5","{0:n2}") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="50">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col6","{0:n2}") %>'>   
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="55">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col7","{0:n2}") %>'>  
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="52">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col8","{0:n2}") %>'>  
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="76">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col9","{0:n2}") %>'>  
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

mark as Answer if it solved your problem. Thanks :)
```